# Upgrade to Bionic kills lvmetad

Tags: upgrade, 18.04

Tonight I upgraded to Bionic. The upgrade was fraught with problems, mainly due to a mixture of PAM and Postgresql where configuring postgresql asks for my PAM password and then ignores me completely forcing me to abort the upgrade mid configure.

My system appears to be mostly working now, but on boot I am told that lvmetad cannot be connected to and there follows a long delay while something is scanned. Disabling lvmetad removes the warning but not the delay.

Can anyone help? I see hints of other articles about this, but when I open the page in the search terms there is nothing useful there.

I see there was a bug reported in May about this which is now apparently fixed.

---

In my kernel log I see some lines like:

> Sep 19 17:13:16 Shikamaru kernel: [ 1815.417699] lvm2-activation[22035]: segfault at d0 ip 00007fbc88f74856 sp 00007ffe47454da0 error 4 in liblvm2app.so.2.2[7fbc88f63000+101000]

I haven't seen these recently though and I am still getting the error.

---

Messing around following clues on the internet, I typed `lvm lvs` and got the following output that might give some more clues:

```
WARNING: Running as a non-root user. Functionality may be unavailable.
/run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: access failed: Permission denied
WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.
/dev/mapper/control: open failed: Permission denied
Failure to communicate with kernel device-mapper driver.
Incompatible libdevmapper 1.02.145 (2017-11-03) and kernel driver (unknown version).
```

However running it with sudo worked. Is it possible that the error during boot has a similar cause?

Comment: You could try reinstalling LVM? segfaults are nasty…

Comment: How do I reinstall? Will the OS let me do apt remove, or is lvm2 a dependency and so I will be unable to remove it without first removing lots of other stuff?

Comment: `sudo apt install lvm2 --reinstall` Nothing should be removed.

Comment: Didn't work. Thanks for the suggestion though. Any more?

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is to run a `fsck` on the drive. There is a bug report which appear to be the same issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lvm2/+bug/1767747 but as usual there's no solution.

Comment: I noticed that after boot lvmetad is running fine. When I looked at running fsck on the drive it said that doing so would corrupt it. How do I avoid that?

Comment: Also, the segfault hasn't happened again, but I still get the message about being unable to connect to lvmetad.

Comment: I'm thinking now that something during boot is trying to use lvm2 before lvmetad (which starts with priority 02) has started. What boot process uses lvm2?

Comment: 'fsck' needs to be run on an unmounted filesystem.